# Golang Error : Package command not found

Tags: go

I'm getting this error when running a .go file.

```
./instance.go: line 1: package: command not found
./instance.go: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./instance.go: line 3: `import ('
```

So far I've seen that the error normally means that GOPATH is not set, however, `echo "$GOPATH"` outputs `/root/go` and my path is currently `/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/go/bin:/bin:/root/go/bin` .

Here's the first few lines of instance.go:

```
package webrun

import (
        "context"
        "crypto/hmac"
        "crypto/rand"
```

Comment: If you are doing `go run instance.go` the issue is that you can't run go files that are not in the main package. `webrun` is a package or library not an executable.

Comment: I have it within a series of other files, what would I run? Here are a few of the files: `
app.yaml      dns.go   instance README.md   templates  util
CONTRIBUTORS  LICENSE  instance.go  connectsk statkeeper  tmpimg`

Comment: Could you add more information: more of the file, how you are trying to "run this go file" specifically, what commands you tried. Where is this package located on your filesystem?

Comment: I'm currently in the directory of /root/go/src/----------------/--------/instance - edited of course. That also contains the rest of the packages' files. I've tried running the file as if SH using ./instance , but that didn't work so I changed to ./instance.go . How do I run it?

Comment: You should have a file with `package main` that has a ` func main() {...` that function should be the start of your program, and that's the file you should `go run`. In that file you can import `dns.go` and any other `.go` file that you have.

Comment: Curious, though: what do you expect `instance.go` to run first, assuming you were able to run it as a program? Does it have a `main` already set up for you?

Comment: Though this is a stupid question as hell. It reduced my time to detect the actual issue :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not Go errors.

However, I was able to reproduce your errors by trying to execute a go source file:

```
$ chmod +x in.go
$ ./in.go
./in.go: line 1: package: command not found
./in.go: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./in.go: line 3: `import ('
```

You can't do this with Go, since it is not interpreted. You need to compile your code to an executable before you can run it.

You can read the help for how to [compile and run a go program here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program).

In your case,

```
go run instance.go
```

will try to compile and run the source file you're executing, but as another commenter points out, code that is not in the `main` package is not designed to be executed directly.

If this is your code, you need to write it inside `package main`, and if it is not, then you're probably trying to execute a library (which means it's not clear to me what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can only ./ files which are runnable. Your go file is not runnable. You need to compile it to binary and do ./(dotslash) on it.

Comment: Note that `./` is not a syntax to run programs, as your explanation seems to imply – it's just a path prefix. Any program that can be located by the shell – `/path/to/program`, or just `program` if the program happens to live in a directory on your `PATH` – can be run by simply making it the first word of a shell command. `./program` works instead of `program` because, unless you installed the program somewhere where the shell knows to look for it, the shell needs to be told exactly where it is. The current directory is not a place where the shell looks for programs by default.